# In Etap, why don't I get a selective tripping sequence when I simulate a fault knowing that the relays' curves are selective with each other?

Tags: simulation, short-circuit, fault

In ETAP, I have two relays that are selective with each other in the Star View. However, when I simulate a fault in the bus that's right after the downstream relay, the tripping sequence is buggy and doesn't behave as I was expecting. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

The tripping sequence must be: CB6 then CB4; aditionally, CB64 and CB65 shouldn't trip. What am I doing wrong?